Ubuntu 24.04 LTS themes not working
I'm trying to change the theme on my ubuntu, but the default applications like file browser, calculator, etc are not changing (I can only change the shell theme and some programs like inkscape), I updated my ubuntu from 22 for 24.04 LTS and before it was working. (I installed user-themes-x, but it still didn't work)
Can i fix it?
Thanks!

This question is similar to: Major software missing after 24.04.1 LTS upgrade. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Afterward, you should be able to change themes as usual

@ArchismanPanigrahi Thanks for the tip, I followed the tutorial, but I still can't change the default applications, like nautilus, I used to put themes in it that changed the colors, background and action icons of the window, but after updating to version 24.04, the Default apps only support yaru themes :(

You can use this for changing themes https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2020/02/change-theme-in-ubuntu

Voted to leave open.

@ArchismanPanigrahi I did the standard procedure, but the system's default apps do not change, in my gnome tweaks, "legacy applications" appears, I believe that the ones I am referring to are the non-legacy ones.
